# How i can get the current state of a lxc container with python?

Tags: python, lxc

I use the lxc module for python and i need the python command to check up the current container state. Or i need a boolean command to check whether the container is current running.

Comment: Do you mean pylxc 0.0.3?

Comment: No the standard ubuntu lxc package!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution at self. It's possible to use the command wait to get a check for the current container state.

```
import lxc

container = lxc.Container("Test")
container.start()
if container.wait("RUNNING", timeout=5)
   container.stop()
   container.destroy()
```

This Command returns a true if it reach the state within the timeout. In other cases returns a false. And so we can make a check for the current container state with the standard library!

Answer (score 0):

Working with lxc (python3-lxc) version 1.0.3 I use

```
import lxc
container = lxc.Container("Test")

container.defined
True
```

to check if the container exists (in /var/lib/lxc)
and

```
container.running
True
```

to see if the container runs.